# slice array and remain with top (x) numbers

Tags: php, arrays

Say i have three different arrays e.g.

```
array1 = (A=7,B=5,C=5,D=4,E=3,F=3,G=2)
array2 = (A=7,B=7,C=5,D=5,E=5,F=3,G=2)
array1 = (A=7,B=7,C=7,D=7,E=3,F=3,G=2)
```

I'm looking for a way that i can slice each of the arrays so that i get the top to 3 numbers e.g.

```
sliced_array1 = (A=7,B=5,C=5) 
sliced_array2 = (A=7,B=7,C=5,D=5,E=5)
sliced_array3 = (A=7,B=7,C=7,D=7)
```

i have tried

```
sliced_array=array_slice($array, 0, 3, true);
```

but the end results is as shown below

```
sliced_array1 = (A=7,B=5,C=5) 
sliced_array2 = (A=7,B=7,C=5)
sliced_array3 = (A=7,B=7,C=7)
```

Comment: What's the logic? Why in second sliced array there are 5 elements?

Comment: Yes, what's the logic here?

Answer (score 1):

I like Nick's solution. That said, here's my old school procedural approach.

```
function array_top($array,$target=3) {
    arsort($array);

    $result=[];
    $previous=NULL;
    foreach ($array as $index=>$value) {
        if ((count($result)>=$target) and ($value!=$previous)) break;
        $result[$index]=$value;
        $previous=$value;
    }

    return $result;
}

$array1=['A'=>7,'B'=>5,'C'=>5,'D'=>4,'E'=>3,'F'=>3,'G'=>2];
$array2=['A'=>7,'B'=>7,'C'=>5,'D'=>5,'E'=>5,'F'=>3,'G'=>2];
$array3=['A'=>7,'B'=>7,'C'=>7,'D'=>7,'E'=>3,'F'=>3,'G'=>2];

print_r(array_top($array1));
print_r(array_top($array2));
print_r(array_top($array3));
```

Interestingly I compared the performance of this function with Nick's solution, iterating each 100k times over the same three examples, and it was a little quicker (0.59s vs 0.98s). If performance is an issue, sometimes old school is worth considering.

Comment: A straight foreach loop will almost always be faster than one of PHPs inbuilt array functions, mainly because you can have a `break` in the loop which the array functions don't allow for. For this question the real advantage of the array functions is readability, I think it's a lot easier to understand what the `array_filter` is doing than your foreach loop. Still, +1 for what *is* a good answer and doing the benchmarking...

Answer (score 0):

This function will give you the result you want. It sorts the array using `arsort` (to retain the keys), then finds the third (possibly equal) highest value, and returns all values in the array that are greater than or equal to that:

```
function top_3($array) {
    // reverse sort the array, retaining keys
    arsort($array);
    // get the third highest value
    $min = array_values($array)[2];
    return array_filter($array, function ($v) use ($min) { return $v >= $min; });
}
print_r(top_3($array1));
print_r(top_3($array2));
print_r(top_3($array3));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [A] => 7
    [B] => 5
    [C] => 5
)
Array
(
    [A] => 7
    [B] => 7
    [C] => 5
    [D] => 5
    [E] => 5
)
Array
(
    [A] => 7
    [B] => 7
    [C] => 7
    [D] => 7
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/vCCkG)